# Turning app offline/online on demand?

Tags: php, yii

we are developing a browser game with Flash (front-end) and Yii 1.1.16 - PHP (Back-end). The game server is a yii web-app that receives requests from the client for the game to progress. Our intent is to have at some point multiple servers.

**What I want to do:** From a central admin panel that we have built I want to be able to set a game server (yii web app) offline with a press of a button and then turn it on.

I have thought of two ways of doing this, one seems more logical from the other, but I want opinions on best practice.

**1)** The first method is to store in the database a boolean field (isOnline) and read it with a select before each action. If it is false I will render the appropriate view informing the requester of the server being offline. The lead programmer is not so fond of this idea because he doesn't want to have one extra query to the database for every request (Do you think it is such a burden?).

**2)** So because of the "problem" above I came up with a different solution that does not use the database. Instead I am using files, in yii fashion. Whenever I want to turn on/off the app I rewrite a file that contains a bool. Then I read this bool before every action/request. Some code follows:

In config/main.php I add this to params:

```
'params'=>array(
    'isOnline' => require(dirname(__FILE__).'/online.php'),
    ...
)
```

the config/online.php file is just this:

```
<?php
//param that decides if server is online or not
return false;
```

And in Controller beforeAction I have this:

```
//If server is offline
if(!Yii::app()->params['isOnline'] )
{
    //allow only 'switch' action
    if(Yii::app()->controller->id.'/'.Yii::app()->controller->action->id == 'test/switch')
    {
        return true;
    }
    //else diplay offline view
    $this->renderPartial('//site/offline');
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

In order to change the online status (the action needs improvement, it just works for now):

```
public function actionSwitch ()
{
    //Get online input, TODO add input checks
    $isOnline = $_GET['online'];

    //Create online.php file contents, using a simple view with an echo inside
    $fileContent = $this->renderPartial('//site/online', array('online' => $isOnline), true);

    //Open config/online.php file
    $file = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'online.php', 'w');

    //Write new content to file
    fwrite($file, $fileContent);

    //Close file
    fclose($file);
}
```

Personally I prefer the first approach and I have doubts about the security of the second approach. What are your opinions (generally and then taking into consideration my colleagues disaproval of the db solution)? Any other approach?

Thanks a lot in advantange.

Comment: There are no problems with 1st approach. Store it in cache if don't want to have 1 more request, and on change - rewrite it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am inexperienced in using the cache. Can you describe the concept in more detail or provide some links?

Comment: After some digging around I think I have understood your suggestion. Also it made me hungry for learning more about chache systems, like memchache, redis etc. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to help. I prefer memcache, but both are good.

Comment: If you go with option 1, consider setting up a `catchAll` route. IMO, that one query has a negligible performance impact. Besides, by the time you run it, your app has already created the DB connection and done a bunch of other stuff. How about altering your web server configuration when you are offline, like redirecting to a static page? That way you won't even have to load yii.

Answer (score 0):

Is much better to use this extension https://github.com/ekaragodin/MaintenanceMode

The only I had added a condition into `init` method of `MaintenanceMode.php`, as I store settings in DB.

*main.php*

```
// First of all I initiate my settings component, to able getting required options from DB
'preload' => array('log','setting','maintenanceMode'),
```

*MaintenanceMode.php*

```
public function init(){
    if ( !$this->enabledMode ) {
        return;
    }

    // Then check your flag
    if ( !Yii::app()->setting->is_offline ) {
        return;
    }
    // ...
```

With this extension you may switch off via main.php just set enabledMode false. Or you may write value into the file and then read it. Also you may setup cache.

Answer (score 0):

Personaly for that simple case, I'd choose your first option plus [Mysql Memory Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html).
You will have the same performance as a cache, without the infraestructure to implement it. While memory comsuption will be mimimal for a one record table.